# Do web servers in a farm have to have synchronized server clocks for ASP.NET State Server?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

Say web server A server clock is set to PST, web server B server clock is set to EST, and the state server clock is set to PST.  Does this matter?  I know it's critical for AppFabric cluster servers to have clock alignment, but what about client web servers to the ASP.NET State Server?

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing the documentation out there I'm not finding anything that confirms or denies this in the Microsoft recommended configuration.  This would be something you could test quite easily with your configuration, but more than likely, the time on the state server is the one that will be used.